# when i add new column in my sql server 2014 Table i cant find it in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, datasource, sql-server-2014

I have a problem with my C# project in `Visual Studio 2017`.
When I'm adding a new column to my SQL server 2014 table I can't find it in VS 2017 data grid and other you can check my 3 picture:

[image]

[image]

[image]

My code in Student.cs class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CURD
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string mcbRozetavalod { get; set; }
        public string mcbMahetavalod { get; set; }
        public string mcbTarikheTavalod { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public bool Gender { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my code in EntityState.cs class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CURD
{
    public enum EntityState
    {
        Unchanged,
        Added,
        Changed,
        Deleted
    }
}
```

Comment: what column exactly?

Comment: you can check my picture bro . . 3 column i have show you [Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbf4M.jpg) [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twH5X.jpg) [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arKSU.jpg)

Comment: Just a tip. Don't paste pictures of code or schemas, put the relevant information in the question, it helps people to help you

Comment: i cant update my Object Student in Data Source visual studio.i have added 3 column in my table sql 2014 name column 1-mcbTarikhetavalod 2-mcbMahetavalod 3-mcbRozetavalod. but i cant find this 3 column in Student object or MetroGrid visualstudio check this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/arKSU.jpg